# How to push a new element to all objects in an array?

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I am trying to push a new element to all the objects in an array but seem to not update.

Any idea what am I doing wrong in here?

So this is my object which contain the `instalments` array.

```
{ _id: 5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d41,
  offer: 5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d40,
  instalments:
   [ { paid: false,
       _id: 5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d44,
       description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
       instalmentAmount: 100000,
       dueTo: 2019-06-06T23:00:00.000Z },
     { paid: false,
       _id: 5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d43,
       description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
       instalmentAmount: 100000,
       dueTo: 2019-06-13T23:00:00.000Z },
     { paid: false,
       _id: 5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d42,
       description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
       instalmentAmount: 91152,
       dueTo: 2019-06-20T23:00:00.000Z } ],
  user: 5cf53a1a8481923f72939940,
  createdAt: 2019-06-05T14:43:08.706Z,
  updatedAt: 2019-06-05T14:43:08.706Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

What I want to do is to add `offer` to all `instalments` objects

The way I am trying to do this is as follow.

`instalmentsGroup` is the object above then I access `instalments` and map

```
const instalments = await instalmentsGroup.instalments.map(
  instalment =>
    Object.assign({}, instalment, { offer: instalmentsGroup.offer })
);
```

Comment: loop through and then for each you add this ?-

Comment: Why you use await?
Without await it works as you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with `await`. There is no need for `await` as `.map` does not return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and so it is not asynchronous.

If you want to edit your object in-place you can use `.forEach` which would loop through each object in your `instalments` array and add the `order` property to it.

See example below:

```js
const obj = {
  _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d41",
  offer: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d40",
  instalments: [{
      paid: false,
      _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d44",
      description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
      instalmentAmount: 100000,
      dueTo: "2019 - 06 - 06 T23: 00: 00.000 Z"
    },
    {
      paid: false,
      _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d43",
      description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
      instalmentAmount: 100000,
      dueTo: "2019 - 06 - 13 T23: 00: 00.000 Z"
    },
    {
      paid: false,
      _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d42",
      description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
      instalmentAmount: 91152,
      dueTo: "2019 - 06 - 20 T23: 00: 00.000 Z"
    }
  ],
  user: "5cf53a1a8481923f72939940",
  createdAt: "2019 - 06 - 05 T14: 43: 08.706 Z",
  updatedAt: "2019 - 06 - 05 T14: 43: 08.706 Z",
  __v: 0
}

const offer = obj.offer;
obj.instalments.forEach(instalment => {
  instalment.offer = offer;
});

console.log(obj.instalments);
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) like you have to map each object to itself, with an additional `offer` property which you can get from the original object. Just make sure to remove `await`. This approach will create a new altered array (and won't modify the original object)

See example below:

```js
const obj = {
  _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d41",
  offer: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d40",
  instalments: [{
      paid: false,
      _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d44",
      description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
      instalmentAmount: 100000,
      dueTo: "2019 - 06 - 06 T23: 00: 00.000 Z"
    },
    {
      paid: false,
      _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d43",
      description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
      instalmentAmount: 100000,
      dueTo: "2019 - 06 - 13 T23: 00: 00.000 Z"
    },
    {
      paid: false,
      _id: "5cf7d4fcc9c5846a69b48d42",
      description: 'Some deacription about yhis instalment',
      instalmentAmount: 91152,
      dueTo: "2019 - 06 - 20 T23: 00: 00.000 Z"
    }
  ],
  user: "5cf53a1a8481923f72939940",
  createdAt: "2019 - 06 - 05 T14: 43: 08.706 Z",
  updatedAt: "2019 - 06 - 05 T14: 43: 08.706 Z",
  __v: 0
}

const offer = obj.offer;
const instalments = obj.instalments.map(instalment => ({...instalment, offer}));

console.log(obj.instalments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without mutating the object might be:

```js
function addOfferToInstalments(obj) {
  let output = { ...obj };
  const offer = output.offer;
  output.instalments = obj.instalments.map(instalment => ({ ...instalment, offer }));
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want updated array of instalments only, then assign an extra property through `map` method

```
const updatedInstallments = instalmentsGroup.instalments.map(obj => {
    obj.offer = instalmentsGroup.offer;
    return obj;
})
```

Also there is no need of `async/await` as `map` does not return a promise.

Comment: Markus had error in his code with await. The rest of code is good.

Comment: Yes, it's of no use there.